# Unable to share URL with facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-opengraph

This one has me stumped.

The URL in question : http://vagabrothers.com/

Using FB's tool: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/ I get the error: `Error parsing input URL, no data was cached, or no data was scraped.`

All the OG meta data looks fine. Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17381124/error-parsing-input-url-no-data-was-scraped-only-with-new-pages-on-my-site

Comment: @ChrisBenseler I saw that answer - in that case they had special characters in the permalink. No the case here

Comment: When I try and test I see "This link is blocked, or you have triggered an excessive amount of scrapes. If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know." Which could be cause by people trying it from here, I guess. Could it be it cached an empty version previously?

Comment: @lemieuxster I got the same message before I ever posted. It's the later (mistake) for sure.

Comment: @elzi can you post your code

Comment: @rajeshujade There is no code. Just the OpenGraph meta data, and attempting to share the URL via facebook.

Comment: @elzi Yes.But right now you have to find a way to unblock your domain first. Else Facebook will not fetch your site(page) data as its block. Hence OG meta is not useful for you :(.even you put it on your pages.

Comment: @elzi First try to explain facebook people why its error. Just click on let us know link. I am not sure they will respond you pretty fast. But Its the only way, you have right now. So write them ASAP.

Comment: @rajeshujade Yeah I emailed them over 2 months ago. Thanks for your answer it's safe to assume it's the right one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to debug as below:

1. Login to facebook.
2. Copy the link which you wants to share on facebook.
3. Paste the link in update status & Check if its working or not.
4. Go to facebook timeline.
5. Paste the link in update status & Check if its working or not.
6. Point 3 & 5 are same. I have mentioned it to make sure its working from both way.
7. If facebook is able to fetch the content from link and you are able to post the link from facebook then you have to debug your code to find the problem
8. If not able to post then try to figure out what facebook errors means. Probably its error from facebook end.

When I tried to share [London Through New Eyes](http://vagabrothers.com/london-through-new-eyes/) & [Vagabrothers Home Page](http://vagabrothers.com/) manually from my facebook account. It shows me Following error:

```
The content you're trying to share includes a link that our security systems detected to be unsafe:

vagabrothers.com

Please remove this link to continue.

If you think you're seeing this by mistake, please let us know.
```

I am attaching the facebook screen shot for your reference.
[image: Facebook Error Log]

**Note:** I have found facebook community link regarding this error: [My website links are seen by facebook as spammy or unsafe](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=10152384414730538).

**Conclusion:** First try to explain facebook people why its error. Just click on let us know link. I am not sure, they will respond you pretty fast. But Its the only way, you have right now. So write them ASAP

Answer (score -4):

Just remove `https://` from the URL.